# openssh with virtual users and chroot

Tags: user-accounts, sftp, openssh, chroot

I'm looking for a way to run a opensshd offering sftp to users as a unprivileged user e.g. on port 8022. This opensshd should take something like a customer passwd file which can include information like username, password etc and put all into per user dedicated folders inside a common root directory. How could this be achieved if possible at all with opensshd?

To make it more clear I need to have:

- opensshd running under a non-root user on some port >1024 with a custom sshd-config file
- possibility to define users for openssh that are not system users of current system provided by e.g. a local text file and ideal without PAM interaction
- some kind of changeroot for this users so `user1` is not able to access data of `user2` during up- and download.

I have found some examples defining a chroot for openssh, but not supporting virtual users without PAM. Now I'm wondering whether it's possible at all.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? Your question is unclear

Comment: Tried to make it more clear — not sure whether I succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openssh does not suppoort virtual users. It can authenticate only using `passwd` or `PAM`. If you are searching for virtual users, you should give a try `vsftpd`.

Comment: In the end we used proftpd